# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am starting my application and getting below error in logs at startup. Weird thing is i amnot getting which table is missing ? Is there a way it can display which table does not exist

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:516) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394) ~[spring-tx-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

It means that your query is trying to use the table which doesn't exists OR it is using the table without having right access.

So, when you start your application, some Spring bean is created and process such query (you can see from stack trace that Spring tx manager is trying to commit the current transaction, so in some place this transaction was opened). You should make sure that all hibernate entities have corresponding table to your schema. If you can't guarantee that, perhaps you can use `<hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto> update </hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto>`

hibernate will do the job for you and creates tables & sequences and so forth according to your entities.

Also you can check what is going on by enabling hibernate logging. You can enable if by setting property "`show_sql`" to "`true`" in your persistence.xml or alternative using

**logback**:

```
 <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />
```

**log4j**:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Comment: Additionally, probably there will be a way to set hibernate to log the queries it does...

Comment: as i posted in my question i want to the name of table which is missing ?

Comment: enable logging, it will be the best way to detect what is going on. See update